# JavaScript variable available over entire class for all methods?

Tags: javascript, variables, scope

When I try to declare a variable in the class outside any method or constructor I get an error. I  want to do like you do in Java and C# for variables available over the entire class. First declare the variable like `var list` outside any method and then assign values to it in the constructor or a method. Or how do you do this in JavaScript?

Comment: Not possible yet with `Class` syntax, but there's a proposal: https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields Or you can wrap everything in an IIFE, declare the variable outside of the `class`, use it, and then return the class.

Comment: @Li357 Because any property assigned to `this` is *not* shared across the entire class - it's individual to each instantiation, but OP sounds like he wants something *shared*.

Comment: @CertainPerformance static getters and setters?

Comment: @Li357 Thank you! It worked. I'm not blaming JavaScript for not knowing those things. But am I the only onle who thinks the syntax is a bit strange? Why not "var this.foo = baz;"?

Comment: @EggBender Wait, your question suggests you want something like a *static variable*. Using `this` essentially makes it an instance variable. Anyways, the reason the syntax like that is because `var` **is a declarator**. It declares a reference you can assign. On the contrary, `this` is already a reference that exists; no need to declare it with `var` thus no `var` on the LHS. You're just adding a property to `this` (the current instance, like Java does).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can **create a private scoope using closures**, and **inside this scope declare your Class globals**, available from everywere inside the Class, but behaving as private when trying to accees them from outside.

```
var myClass =  (function(){
    // your variable
    var privateVar = 'i am private!';
    // retun your class
    return  class Rectangle{
       constructor() {
           console.log(privateVar)
       }
    }
})()
```